# Laying out UIButtons - easy way?

Tags: iphone

I am making a table which has a row that looks like the "To:" line in the Apple Mail app. When you add new people to Mail from your address book, their name shows up in a rounded button.

I can create the button and use sizeToFit to make it fit snugly around the text - no problem.

However, once I do that, I can't figure out how wide the button has become. Is there an easy way to just stick a bunch of buttons in a cell and have it wrap as necessary automatically, or do I have to manually calculate the width and if it goes beyond the end of the screen, move to the next row?

Also, how do you get the width of a sizeToFit'ted button? button.frame returns null. Most perplexing.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Joe Hewitt's [three20 project](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master), a collection of custom UI elements for the iPhone that were used in the development of the Facebook app.

The two classes you would be particularly interested are [TTMessageController](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) and [TTPickerTextField](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTPickerTextField.h).

From the project site:

> TTMessageController emulates the
>   message composer in Apple's Mail app.
>   You can customize it to send any kind
>   of message you want. Include your own
>   set of message fields, or use the
>   standard "To:" and "Subject:".
>   Recipient names can be autocompleted
>   from a data source that you provide.
>
> TTPickerTextField is a type-ahead
>   UITextField. As you type it searches a
>   data source, and it adds bubbles into
>   the flow of text when you choose a
>   type-ahead option. I use this in
>   TTMessageController for selecting the
>   names of message recipients.